# Simple and complex form many to many with collection and entities

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine-orm

I got this problem.

A user must check one answers from a multiple choice form, but the form must handle more than one question.

```
<form>
    Question1:
    This is the question 1 text? (static text question.text property)
      - Answer 1 (radio)
      - Answer 2 (radio)
      - Answer 3 (radio)

    Question2:
    This is the question 2 text? (static text question.text property)
      - Answer 4 (radio)
      - Answer 5 (radio)
      - Answer 6 (radio)
      - Answer 7 (radio)

    Question3:
    This is the question 3 text? (static text question.text property)
      - Answer 8 (radio)
      - Answer 9 (radio)

 [submit button]

</form>
```

I have two problemas here. First the form, how i can build that form?
And second, the validations.
Each question has many answers, not the same, and not the same quantity.

I try with collections and entities, but... i get only frustation :(

How i can resolve this?

Comment: Look at this bundle, maybe a good solution : http://www.craue.de/sf2playground/en/CraueFormFlow/

Comment: If you are looking build something like a quiz you may even have a look at this bundle: https://github.com/lms42/SmirikQuizBundle